# Sequencer in Java application cannot anymore play MIDI track on Windows

Tags: java, windows-10, midi

I had a Java application that generated, then played, some simple one track MIDI music on the PC's speakers. It worked perfectly well on several versions of Windows, but I tried it recently on Windows 10 and it fails:

- no sound is played
- it seems to be stalled (never gets out of the "isRunning" state)

Code (I just updated it so that is is testable and closer to a minimal example):

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;


class zik2 {
  static Track track;

  static int VEL=50;
  static int PROG=21; // 19: church organ, 21: harmonica

  static int[] gamme = {60,62,64,65,67,69,71,72,74,76,77,79,81,83,84};

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Sequence seq=new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,1);
      track=seq.createTrack();

      long tick=0;

      ShortMessage sm;
      sm=new ShortMessage();      

      sm.setMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE,PROG,0);
      track.add(new MidiEvent(sm,tick));

      for(int k=0; k<7; k++) {
        int l=gamme[k];
        sm.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON,0,l,VEL); 
        track.add(new MidiEvent(sm,tick++));
        sm.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF,0,l,0); 
        track.add(new MidiEvent(sm,tick+1));
      }

      Sequencer player=MidiSystem.getSequencer();
      player.open();
      player.setSequence(seq);
      player.setTempoInBPM(60);
      player.start();
      System.out.println("Hello (world)");
      do { Thread.sleep(50); } while(player.isRunning());
      player.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Update : the following short test worked, so the problem is with the sequencer?

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      try {
          Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
          synthesizer.open();

          MidiChannel[] channels = synthesizer.getChannels();

          channels[0].noteOn(60, 60);
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          channels[0].noteOff(60);
          Thread.sleep(1000);

          synthesizer.close();
      } catch (Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: does the pc have an internal speaker? What happens if you use the normal audio output?

Comment: `do {} while(player.isRunning());` would use up 100% CPU of one of your processor cores, would make your motherboard heat up, and could prevent other processes from running smoothly.

Comment: @Tschallacka it is a laptop and I infer the java program tries to use the normal audio output... which should be the speakers built in the laptop, right?

Comment: mmm windows 10 - wait till you get to 11

Comment: +gpasch tempting... do you think it will be out on March 15th? ;-)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks, I updated the code but the problem remains.

Comment: I usually get the sequencer by MidiDevice.Info[] md=MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo(); but MidiSystem.getSequencer() works also - if the sequencer is running and doesnt play any sound it probably doenst work/doesnt understand the input - you might go through all the available sequencers and try the one that works

Comment: +gpasch Thanks! I get 4 results: -
Gervill: Software MIDI Synthesizer -
Microsoft MIDI Mapper: Windows MIDI_MAPPER -
Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth: Internal software synthesizer -
Real Time Sequencer: Software sequencer -
I'll try them.

Comment: +gpasch I tried the Midi devices and only one of them could be cast to a Sequencer. It does not stall but produces no sound :(

Comment: I also discovered that the Sequencer does not stall, it just takes much longer than usual to proceed (and produces no sound)